# Calling Java vararg method from Scala with primitives

Tags: java, scala, interop, variadic-functions, primitive-types

I have the following code in Java:

```
public class JavaClass {

    public static void method( Object x ) {
    }

    public static void varargsMethod( Object... x ) {
    }

}
```

When I try and access it from Scala,

```
object FooUser {
  JavaClass.method(true)
  JavaClass.varargsMethod(true) // <-- compile error
}
```

I get the following compile error:

> type mismatch;  found   : Boolean(true)  required: java.lang.Object Note: primitive types are not implicitly converted to AnyRef. You can safely force boxing by casting x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]

The error message is very helpful and shows how to fix the error, but I was wondering why the compiler is (apparently) happy to implicitly convert a `scala.Boolean` in one method call but not the other. Is this a bug or intentional?

**Updated to add:**
I'm using Scala 2.8. If I make the varargsMethod signature

```
public static <T> void varargsMethod(T... xs) {
```

instead, then the error also goes away. I'm still puzzled as to why the compiler can't figure it out.

Comment: THANK YOU! This trick <T> void varargsMethod(T... xs) works!!!

Answer (score 5):

Scala varargs and Java varargs are different. You need to [do a conversion](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Scala-varargs-to-Java-varargs-td2005925.html):

```
def g(x: Any*) = x.asInstanceOf[scala.runtime.BoxedObjectArray]
.unbox(x.getClass)
.asInstanceOf[Array[Object]]  
...
JavaClass.varargsMethod(g(true))
```

or ([in 2.8.0+](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1360))

```
JavaClass.varargsMethod(java.util.Arrays.asList(true))
```

Comment: The 2.8 "Arrays.asList(true)" version does not work, as it gives a single argument to "varargsMethod" of type "Arrays$ArrayList". However, finding a workaround is not really a problem -- the error message shows how to fix the error -- rather I wanted to know why the compiler wouldn't compile this call when it will for others in similar situations.

Comment: I'd love to get an answer to this as well.

Comment: so does Scala > 2.8 return type BoxedObjectArray is not a member of package runtime

Answer (score 2):

Since `scala.Boolean` is a subclass of `scala.AnyVal` but not `scala.AnyRef` (translated to `java.lang.Object`), a `Boolean` cannot be passed to a method expecting `Object`(s).

You can use the companion object `scala.Boolean` to "box" (in Java's sense, of course) a `boolean` into `java.lang.Boolean`:

```
JavaClass.varargsMethod(Boolean.box(true))
```

The other `AnyVal` classes have corresponding `box` methods (e.g. `Int.box`). There are also `unbox` methods to do the opposite.

A more complicated use case:

```
JavaClass.varargsMethod(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4).map(Int.box): _*) // passes 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I don't know when these were added to the standard library, but with these you don't have to use the implementation classes of `scala.runtime.*`.

Answer (score 1):

Note, with Scala version 2.13.x, this works out-of-the-box (no pun) without having to manually box the value.

Answer (score 0):

Probably can file a bug about it.  It seems like it should throw an exception in both cases or neither.  Not sure it's something that will ever be fixed as it probably is caused by some cleverness in the implementation of varargs that prevents the boxing from taking place.